# Entity Framework 6 ability to reference nested objects on closed context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a class which loads all of the data I want on screen.

I am loading all the data within a using statement and returning the resultant records in a higher class.

I am able to loop through the objects, but any nested objects are unavailable and I get the error "The function evaluation requires all threads to run." when I try to inspect the objects.

The returned error to the web page is "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

Is there a way in EF6 for me to load all the objects and nested objects and make them available outside of the context?

Comment: As quick fix, try adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in your connection string to see if that solves it.

Comment: It is already set to true

Comment: You definitely need to join it on fetch then.. from the conversation in one of the answer below looks like there is a mapping problem as well. May I suggest you use this? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838 I have been using it in several projects and it is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using statement will automatically dispose the object.

You can use include while fetching main entities to also fetch the related entities.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Yeah I was just looking at that but now I get another error "does not declare a navigation property with the name 'tblAddresses'".

Answer (score 0):

DbContext isn't supposed to be used for a long time. It's better to instantiate context, copy all data that you need from it in to some array/collection and dispose it right after that. Then you can access your data with this array/collection.

Example:
In Controller class

```
Person[] people = Repo.GetAllPeople();
```

And in Repository class you have something like:

```
public People[] GetAllPeople()
{    
    try
    {
        MyDbContext cont = new MyDbContext();        
        return cont.People.ToArray();
    } 
    catch { return null; }    
    finally { cont.Dispose(); }
}
```

P.S.
And *yes* - using statement is nothing else then just :

```
try
{
   ...instantiate some_resource that inherits from IDisposable
   ...do something with this resource
}
finally {  some_resource.Dispose(); }
```